# Group items in an M*N array based on two columns

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of items, with the following column names and values -

[image]

I have to group the items into different categories, based on multiple criteria -

1. All targets will be grouped based on Target Groups
2. Each target group will then be subdivided based on which source it is mapped to.
3. If each target has multiple sources, then all the targets having same set of sources will be grouped together.
4. This grouping will be used later to categorize another list into groups.

In the above example, (T1, T2) and (T5, T6) will grouped together and T3, T4 will be separate:

[image]

Now, to achieve the above grouping, what might be the best approach, offering the best time complexity?

I have tried an approach where we traverse the initial list, add the list of sources to a target dictionary. Then, apply grouping based on equality of sources. But, this is proving to be costly. Is there a better method than this?

Comment: If I understand correctly then I believe your last line should be S2 | T3 | TG2

Comment: does all of the Targets contains THE SAME NUMBER of Sources?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I delibrately avoided TG2, since any TG2 collection would be a separate group. I just addded one target group for simplicity.

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja No, that is the issue. Each target might have different number of sources.

Comment: how about something xml-like?

Comment: Updated the data, hopefully it is more clear now :)